# created by the idea of

Tags: grammar, expressions, phrase-requests

What is the correct way to say that something was 'created by the idea of someone else...' For example, if John Doe came up with an idea and I developed it into a project, I would say:

> This project was ___________ [*created by the idea of*] John Doe.

But Google gives only two results for the exact search of "created by the idea of": https://www.google.ca/#q=%22created+by+the+idea+of%22&*

... which probably means that I am wrong (that this is not correct).

Comment: As a rule, *ideas* don't create projects - creation is something *people* do. You'd find more hits for something like [*was developed from an idea of John Doe's*](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB712GB712&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22was+developed+from+an+idea+of%22&*) or *...using John Doe's ideas*.

Comment: Do you mean that John Doe had the idea and created it, or John Doe had the idea and someone else created it?

Comment: @Barmar Someone else created it.

Comment: The project is based on an idea from John Doe.

Comment: I think it depends on the field of your project. For example, in the film industry it's not uncommon to give credit as "*based upon an idea by John Doe*” as part of the writing credits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The project was first **conceptualized** by John Doe.

[Conceptualize](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/conceptualize)
Form a concept or idea of (something)

Also for a more 'project' orientated definition:

[Conceptualization](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/conceptualization.html):

> The ability to invent or formulate an idea or concept. The
>   conceptualization phase of a project occurs in the initial design
>   activity when the scope of the project is drafted and a list of the
>   desired design features and requirements is created.

Answer (score 3):

> This project was ***inspired by*** John Doe.

oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com:

> **[inspire](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/inspire)** *verb*
>   **2**. [usually passive] **inspire something**
>   **to give somebody the idea for something**, especially something artistic or that shows imagination
>
> His paintings
>   were clearly ***inspired by*** Monet’s work.

Answer (score 1):

We could say

> This project was John Doe's brainchild.

This means the idea came from his brain, that is to say, he thought of it.

Here is a link to [brainchild](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/brainchild) in the Oxford dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

In the academic humanities we tend to use *conceive*:

> The modern notion of dialectic was conceived by Hegel.

And popular media and advertising employ a word derived from the Latin passive participle of the same root:

> Concept by John Doe.